# How to cancel call created with AMI originate

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am wondering if there is an easy way to hangup a channel created with Originate?

What I do is following:

- Call in dialplan triggers Agi;
- Agi starts AMI: Originate with Channel "SIP/201".
- Now the extension rings. At answer I can bridge the channels. But, if the calling party leaves the call before the call is answered, I would like to stop the outgoing call. When I send AMI Hangup with Channel "SIP/201", It can't hangup originated call.
- I can stop that call using 'hangup request channelname' using CLI
- but how to hangup call using program.

please help me. how to hangup originated call

Answer (score 0):

If calling party leave call,it will be auto-hanguped with CANCEL cause.

You also can use AMI action Hangup

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Hangup

BTW, very likly you just doing it wrong way.

Comment: Thank you for reply, my condition is that I want to record each and every incoming call in asterisk without passing to any extension. for some special numbers i need to only listen them with recording that's why i am originating call. the incoming call in asterisk will be like 3 way call. i dont need to speak there...

Comment: There are no 3way here. You have use Dial application. But better read books or hire expert.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to share my solution for cancelling issued `Originate` actions via AMI, since I haven't found clear solution anywhere else.

1. Start a call (must be async)

```
Action: Originate
Timeout: 20000
Channel: SIP/007
Callerid: TEST
Context: default
Exten: 12345678900
Priority: 1
Async: yes
ActionID: 001
```

2. Wait for `Newchannel` event which will be generated in few milliseconds

```
Event: Newchannel
Privilege: call,all
Channel: SIP/007-0000001c
ChannelState: 0
ChannelStateDesc: Down
CallerIDNum: 007
CallerIDName: Test
ConnectedLineNum: <unknown>
ConnectedLineName: <unknown>
Language: en
AccountCode:
Context: default
Exten: s
Priority: 1
Uniqueid: 1681218827.44
Linkedid: 1681218827.44
```

3. Now it is possible to cancel this request using actual channel id

```
Action: Hangup
Channel: SIP/007-0000001c
ActionID: 002
```